# Are these queries vulnerable to injection in mysql

Tags: php, exploit, sql-injection, mysql

The queries below show SQL injection in appscans for MySQL.
Is there a way to do a proof of concept or otherwise to how can they be exploited?

```
INSERT INTO cscart_sessions (session_id, expiry) values('6432e5ecf6c81730aa70c2b05415fe6d OR ' '','1468236649')

SELECT session_id FROM cscart_sessions WHERE session_id='6432e5ecf6c81730aa70c2b05415fe6d' AND expiry>'1468229900'
```

Comment: So your app scans show that the code can be exploited with an SQL injection?  Do they tell you which vulnerabilities exist?

Comment: Just showing the full final queries will not help very much in telling how they can be exploited. We would need the PHP code that generates them to do that, otherwise it is impossible to know what is hardcoded SQL and what is untrusted data, and how that untrusted data is validated.

Comment: Yes they show its sql injection, and in example i could see the query like SELECT session_id FROM cscart_sessions WHERE session_id=6432e5ecf6c81730aa70c2b05415fe6d' AND expiry>'1468229900' a single quote added to request and i get mysql error in response

Comment: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.11.1.24
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0 Iceweasel/44.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: csid=6432e5ecf6c81730aa70c2b05415fe6d'; cart_languageC=EN; secondary_currencyC=usd; acsid=0c3aff9aa7afc1dd90eb8acb72b03530; cart_languageA=EN; secondary_currencyA=usd
Connection: close

Comment: Response snippet:
<p><b><span style='font-weight: bold; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family: Courier;'>Database error:</span></b>&nbsp;1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1468302114'' at line 1<br>
<b><span style='font-weight: bold; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family: Courier;'>Invalid query:</span></b>&nbsp;SELECT session_id FROM cscart_sessions WHERE session_id='6432e5ecf6c81730aa70c2b05415fe6d'' AND expiry>'1468302114'</p><hr noshade width='100%'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're directly using the SesssionId in your query, without escaping the SQL special characters then **YES** the Queries are vulnerable to SQL Injection.

For example, 
Someone could send request to the server with following cookie :

```
csid=a'; DROP TABLE cscart_sessions;
```

And your `SELECT` query will execute to drop the table.

Or a cookie like this :

```
csid=a' or 1=1 or '' = '
```

will select everything in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not the code that makes these queries is properly sanitizing inputs, you may or may not have a vulnerability.

Another factor would be whether the construction of the queries is parameterized or simple uses concatenation.

As commenters have pointed out, there is no way to tell for sure based on the information you've supplied.

Comment: Will page source help, i do not have access to anything else, its more of a black box testing.

Comment: If it's a black box situation, then you will just have to try queries and see if they work. This is typically done through inputs in the app that will make queries to the DB. Start with simple things like ` or 1=1;--` and go from there. There are some great YouTube videos that will guide you through various techniques you can try.

It can be a grueling process, but incredibly rewarding if/when you manage to inject something. Once you've achieved injection, the sky is the limit!

Comment: I am getting my mysql error when i append csid value with single quote, like csid=6432e5ecf6c81730aa70c2b05415fe6d' . This query send a select query but when i try with some other combination like ' or 1=1-- or anything else it sends an insert query. Is there a way for sql injection in Insert query.

Comment: Absolutely! If you can get an INSERT query to run, not only can you deface the table, it likely means you have free reign of the DB.
One technique you may find useful, as it sounds like you have access to the DB logs, is to concatenate queries. Obviously, you wouldn't see the results in the webpage response, but you will see it in the logs. Another useful one would be to do a UNION SELEC with another table to see if you can get at other tables in the same manner.
Check out Joseph McCray's talks on YouTube for a very thorough walk-through. NSFW Warning: The guy cusses like a sailor.

Comment: Sorry, my firewall won't let me properly spell out UNOIN SELECT!

Comment: Got the admin access, now trying to upload a php-reverse-shell.jpeg to connect to server from browser. Thanks above was quiet helpful.